# Verifying if a DC is a RODC

Tags: windows, domain, controller

I'm in a situation where I'm trying to help out a friend who has little knowledge of his system. He is trying to install a program onto his domain controller and it gives an error stating that it cannot be installed on a RODC. This is the only DC that he has so I am assuming it is not a RODC. Is there a specific way I can have him determine what kind of server this was loaded as? I had him send me a `dcdiag /v` printout, but I couldn't determine one way or another if it was read only or not.

Answer (score 6):

In 'Active Directory Users And Computers' browse to the RODC's computer object the DC Type should contain say ReadOnly if it is a RODC. The computer object properties on tab 'Managed by' should also show what type of DC it is.

Comment: The DC type states that it is GC. I'm assuming that is Global Catalog. Under the Managed by tab everything is blank. I'm confident that this is properly installed and not a RODC. I'll have to tell my friend to contact the software vendor for support installing the package he wants installed.

Comment: @JArrington1 Correct - it'll display both "GC" and "RODC" in that field if it's both.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the DC detail with the help of PS. Go to your DC and type

nltest /DSGETDC:

i.e.
 PS C:\Users\44012231-730> nltest /DSGETDC:ABC.COM
           DC: \SKYBLUE.ABC.COM
      Address: \123.11.1.45
     Dom Guid: 44c23f06-dff1-47c9-92e2-dd060e2c2b11
     Dom Name: ABC.COM
  Forest Name: ABC
 Dc Site Name: 0SHSRNKDKJ
Our Site Name: GSKDJFOENL
        Flags: GC DS LDAP KDC TIMESERV **WRITABLE** DNS_DC DNS_DOMAIN DNS_FOREST CLOSE_SITE FULL_SECRET WS 0xC000
The command completed successfully

Comment: Can you please edit your post to improve formattiing?